# Android/Java File.canRead() strange issue

Tags: java, android

Good day!

There is an interesting situation:
In my code I walk around `/sdcard/` on my `Android` phone and try to find a pair of files.
While I open directory I try to :

```
if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length != 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                if (file.isDirectory() && file.canRead()) {
                       for (File innerFile : file.listFiles()) {
```

I thought that

```
file.canRead()
```

is enough for checking  access to this Directory, but it seems I was wrong.

I have a directory

```
/storage/emulated/0/multirom
```

with 'ls'

```
drwxrwx--x 10 root sdcard_rw      4096 2016-08-31 14:21 multirom
```

That means  - I can

```
 cd multirom/
```

But I can not

```
$ ls
ls: .: Permission denied
```

So as I see - `file.canRead()` checks only execute ability so someone can "enter"(execute) directory, but not "read" the content.

The question is - is there anywhere mentioning about this? I could not find details about it. Why method canRead() checks execute bit instead of checking both execute and read bits?
Maybe this will help someone with such problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation from the Android javadoc:

[Android File class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#canRead())

There is also a canExecute() method on the File class.

Comment: My question was not about this. Why method canRead() checks execute bit instead of checking both execute and read?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure you'll find much more detail than is available in the Android documentation. Can you investigate the canRead() method in the source code to see exactly what it is doing?